# Callback from whatsapp after sharing message

Tags: android, callback, sharing, whatsapp

in my application I have to give some points to users after sharing some link. I have done this for Facebook and Twitter because they were giving a call back after successful sharing. Is there any option to detect wether the link is shared or not in whats app ?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: no, actually since there is no sdk available for whatsapp, we can't get to know that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some readings, The answer is no. because whatsapp doesn't have an SDK, so we can't get to know whether message shared or not, but we will get callback in `onActivityResult()` when we returned from whatsapp to our app.

Comment: When the users click the share button then Whatsapp will open but the user will not share it with anybody and then this will return to the app in this scenario,  you will always get a callback, so this is not right.